# Exceptions in apex class constructor

Tags: constructor, salesforce, apex-code

I've been trying to catch an exception in a Salesforce custom apex class but doesn't seems to work.

In this case I have a controller constructor that initializes the environment and I am trying to catch exceptions in the constructor, but doesn't work, the exception is not catched.

```
public MyController(){
  try{
    this.myVar = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParam');
    ....

   }
   catch( System.StringException se ){
     ..
   }
   catch( System.NullPointerException ne ){
     ..
   }
   catch( Exception e ){
     ..
   }
  ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with @mmix.

Following operation can never result in any exception.

```
ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('myParam');
```

In fact catching NPE(NullPointerException) is bad practice, as these are runtime exceptions and one should check for a variable != null OR variable == null instead of depending on NPE exceptions. Code flow will be too hard to maintain and understand if you use try catch blocks like this.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing to catch here

`currentPage()` is not null if inside controller/extension

`getParameters()` is not null even if parameter list is empty

`get('myParam')` may or may not return null, but regardless that value gets stored in myVar

only if you were to later try and reference myVar's instance members will you get `System.NullPointerException`, even storing null myVar in database is valid.

Comment: In my case myVar is of type Id, so if someone wants to change the Ids in the url it will throw the exception, also after the this myVar there is initialization code that could throw other exceptions, but even though i use Exception they are not catched

Comment: The only way myVar can be null is if myParam is missing altogether from URL. You should check for that using if statement. using NULL as ID is valid up to a point where you try to store it in a not-null field (raising DML exception) or you try to reference one of ID instance methods (raising NPE). Everything else will work smoothly without NPE.